# How to display the date without time from get operation in javascript (node js, mysql)?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

created a simple crud application on nodejs and mysql. but have one problem, cant display the date without time and in the proper format.

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Rick Sanchez",
"dob": "1960-05-20T19:00:00.000Z",
"phone": "84351548898",
"comments": "Genius in the galaxy"
},
```

in the phpmyadmin, the date in the dob i chose as the datetime format.

Comment: This is the end result when I use the GET operation. When I use GET operation, this is how it shows me the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should use the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library which is more powerful and has great options(like format).

In your case, you can do the following.

```
let date = moment('1960-05-20T19:00:00.000Z').utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
console.log(date);
```

Comment: Do I have to write this for every user? I have 2 more users in the my table

Comment: I believe there maybe some kind of transformer or ORM. that maps the SQL data before sending it to the end-user. So you can add this code over there.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can I email you with a screenshot for you to see the problem? I'm new in web development and desperate for help :(

Comment: you can post the code here as well as the part of the question.

Comment: <div class="col-6">
    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <input class="form-control" type="date" value="{{this.dob}}" id="floatingInput" placeholder="DoB" name="dob">
        <label for="floatingInput">DoB</label>
    </div>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toLocaleDateString()` method,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

```js
const obj = {
 "id": 1,
 "name": "Rick Sanchez",
 "dob": "1960-05-20T19:00:00.000Z",
 "phone": "84351548898",
 "comments": "Genius in the galaxy"
};

const dateOfBirth = (new Date(obj.dob)).toLocaleDateString();

console.log(dateOfBirth);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a date Object from the string with `const myDate = new Date(myString)` and then use a method like `myDate.toLocaleDateString()` to retrieve only the date part

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however i'm new in web development and dont quite get what you mean creating objects with strings